# Summarise unique values from column by group from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with some metrics about the species that occur across places where I am doing an assessment.  A species can occur in the same place more than once with the same score because there are different coordinate locations in each place.

Here a sample of the data set:

| PLACE | species | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 348 | Cercopithecus mitis mitis | 4.950851 |
| 597 | Acinonyx jubatus | 6.332438 |
| 597 | Acinonyx jubatus | 6.332438 |
| 597 | Acomys johannis | 4.655138 |
| 597 | Acomys cineraceus | 3.646404 |
| 873 | Aepyceros melampus | 5.668386 |
| 873 | Aepyceros melampus | 5.668386 |
| 873 | Aepyceros melampus | 5.668386 |
| 873 | Alcelaphus buselaphus | 5.075547 |

I want to summarise the values from column `score` (mean, median, deviance, and variance) by place from unique species.  I tried using `dplyr` as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)
dataSpp %>% group_by(PLACE) %>% summarise_each(funs(n_distinct(.)))
```

But that did not work.  What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~PLACE,                     ~species,   ~score,
  348L,  "Cercopithecus mitis mitis", 4.950851,
  597L,           "Acinonyx jubatus", 6.332438,
  597L,           "Acinonyx jubatus", 6.332438,
  597L, "Acomys johannis cineraceus", 4.655138,
  597L,         "Aepyceros melampus", 5.646404,
  873L,         "Aepyceros melampus", 5.668386,
  873L,         "Aepyceros melampus", 5.668386,
  873L,      "Alcelaphus buselaphus", 5.075547
)

df |>
  distinct() |>
  summarize(
    mean = mean(score),
    median = median(score),
    sd = sd(score),
    .by = c(PLACE)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   PLACE  mean median     sd
#>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   348  4.95   4.95 NA    
#> 2   597  5.54   5.65  0.843
#> 3   873  5.37   5.37  0.419
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think I didn't explain it right. I meant that I would like to get the mean, median and standard deviation values for each place (without considering duplicate species). Not grouped by place and species, but values grouped by place considering unique species. For example, as you code above, for place "597" the mean would be "5.54466" and the median "5.646404".

Comment: So you mean you'd like to remove duplicate rows before summarizing? I updated the answer.